# To which DBs can I connect via DB LINK from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, dblink

To which DBs can I connect, via DB Link, form a Oracle DB? Is there a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the ODBC gateway (which does not require additional licensing), you can connect to any database that you can get an ODBC driver for.

If you are asking about using one of the platform-specific gateways (which do require additional licensing), Oracle has gateways for SQL Server, Sybase, Teradata, and Informix as well as for VSMA, IMS, DRDA, APPC, and Adabas.  You can take a look at the [various user's guides](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.all_books#index-GAT) for all these gateways in the Oracle documentation.